# Extract JSON Value From Nested List

Tags: python, json, omdbapi

I am using the OMDb API to pull movie/tv show data using Python. I am trying to get the IMDB, Rotten Tomatoes, and Metacritic ratings from the following JSON.

```json
{
    "title": "One Hundred and One Dalmatians",
    "year": "1961",
    "rated": "G",
    "ratings": [
        {
            "source": "Internet Movie Database",
            "value": "7.2/10"
        },
        {
            "source": "Rotten Tomatoes",
            "value": "98%"
        },
        {
            "source": "Metacritic",
            "value": "83/100"
        }
    ],
    "response": "True"
}
```

I want the value of "98%" from the nested list of ratings for the Rotten Tomatoes source. How can I get that instead of using something like `omdb_media['ratings'][1]['Value']`? There isn't always an entry for Rotten Tomatoes and I also can't guarantee the order since there may not be an entry for IMDB or Metacritic, but one for Rotten Tomatoes, so its index changes.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to search through the JSON and have it get that value by being able to search for "Rotten Tomatoes".

Is this possible? How would I go about doing it?

Comment: `for sv in omdb_media['ratings']` is the loop you want, this should be enough to get you started. you will need to add an `if` statement to check what the `source` is as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
json ={
    "title": "One Hundred and One Dalmatians",
    "year": "1961",
    "rated": "G",
    "ratings": [
        {
            "source": "Internet Movie Database",
            "value": "7.2/10"
        },
        {
            "source": "Rotten Tomatoes",
            "value": "98%"
        },
        {
            "source": "Metacritic",
            "value": "83/100"
        }
    ],
    "response": "True"
}

for rating in json["ratings"] :
    if(rating["source"] == "Rotten Tomatoes") :
        print(rating["value"])
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was trying to do, I just couldn't figure out how to put it into code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each entry in the `ratings` list has a source and a value, and that each rating has a unique source, you can do the following:

```py
# Generate a new list, with any ratings that aren't from Rotten Tomatoes removed.
rotten_tomatoes_ratings = filter(lambda x: x['source'] == 'Rotten Tomatoes', omdb_media['ratings'])

# Only execute the following code if there exists a rating from Rotten Tomatoes.
if rotten_tomatoes_ratings:
   [rating] = rotten_tomatoes_ratings
   # Do stuff with rating...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just ask for the `next()` rating where the `source` is `"Rotten Tomatoes"`. The final `None` in this is the result if not sources match, this can be any default value you want:

```
source = 'Rotten Tomatoes'

rt = next((rating['value'] 
      for rating in d['ratings']
      if rating['source'] == source), None)

print(rt)
# 98%
```